# Bootstrap navigation bar leaves an empty space

Tags: space, nav

I got an empty space between my navigation bar and the next division. I don't know where it comes from, here's my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<!-- Navigation bar -->
<div id = "menu"> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Menu</a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class = "menu-view"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          <li class = "menu-edit"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Undo</a></li>
          <li class = "menu-edit"><a>Redo <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a></li>
        </ul>

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class = "menu-edit"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save</a></li>
          <li class = "menu-edit"><a id = "a-cancel" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div style = "background-color: red">
  Empty space above me !
</div>

</body>
  
</html>
```

I'm adding these extra lines because my post need some more detail before posting... what the heck is that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First be careful you have load error : 
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6

Try this I add class to nav which avoid margin-bottom :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
     .margin-bottom-0 {
         margin-bottom: 0;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<!-- Navigation bar -->
<div id = "menu"> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default margin-bottom-0">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Menu</a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class = "menu-view"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          <li class = "menu-edit"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Undo</a></li>
          <li class = "menu-edit"><a>Redo <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a></li>
        </ul>

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class = "menu-edit"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save</a></li>
          <li class = "menu-edit"><a id = "a-cancel" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div style = "background-color: red">
  Empty space above me !
</div>

</body>
  
</html>
```